# How to update multiple object properties with an array of objects in redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

How can I update multiple properties in my state object with and array of objects?

I have my state in this format:

```
{
 1: { id: 1, values: [ 1, 2] },
 2: { id: 2, values: [ 1, 2] }
}
```

In my reducer I receive the data to update the state in this format:

```
[
 { id: 1, values: [ 3, 4] },
 { id: 2, values: [ 3, 4 ] }
]
```

I want to be able to add the values from the objects coming into the reducer to matching object values in the state.

I would like to end up with:

```
{
 1: { id: 1, values: [ 1, 2, 3, 4] },
 2: { id: 2, values: [ 1, 2, 3, 4] }
}
```

I tried to map through this but then it was returning my state into an array. I want to keep my state as an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the data before it reaches your reducer, whether that's in an action, thunk, saga, or component.

```
const transform = (data = []) => {
    const mappedData = {};
    data.forEach(item => mappedData[item.id] = item);
    return mappedData
}

// ...
data = transform(data)
```

This keeps reducer logic cleaner

```
const myReducer = (state = {}, { type, data = {}, id, values = [] }) => {
    case 'SET_ALL':
        return data;
    case 'SET_MULTIPLE':
        return {
            ...state,
            ...data
        };
    case 'SET':
        return {
            ...state,
            [id]: values
        };
    case 'APPEND_VALUES':
        return {
            ...state,
            [id]: { 
                ...state[id], 
                values: [...state[id].values, ...values] 
            }
        }
    default:
        return state;
}
```

Comment: Once you have transformed the data, are you sending all of the objects at once or one at a time to the reducer?

Comment: In this example you could send all at once in a `'SET_ALL'` or `'SET_MULTIPLE'` action, or you could set one at a time in a `'SET'` action

Comment: The part that I'm struggling with is in the 'SET_MULTIPLE', I want to concat the values array from the state with the values array in data, if I spread both state and data, I will only get the new data values.

Comment: spreading state and data will concat any new values and overwrite any existing ones

Comment: Ah, I want to keep the existing values, for example if the state object value was [ 1 ] and the data object value was [ 2 ], I want the new states value to be [ 1, 2 ]. This is where I seem to get it wrong and end up with only the new value.

Comment: I made an edit to the question to make it a bit clearer, thanks.

Comment: added a handler to append on a single item. Multiple might be tricky, but I'm sure you could figure that out if you get the gist of this code

Comment: I used this in the SET_MULTIPLE let newState = {
    ...state
};
for (let obj in data) {
    newState[obj].values = [...newState[obj].values, ...data[obj].values]
}
return newState;  If you want to add to your answer to help others.

Answer (score 4):

The map solution was almost correct! I would recommend doing `forEach` instead and don't return anything, but rather access a copy of `state` by `id` and modify those values (make sure you deep clone your state to avoid mutation). Then return the new state:

```
const myReducer = (state, action) => {
  const newState = someDeepCloneFunction(state);
  action.forEach(obj => {
    newState[obj.id] = obj.values
  })
  return newState
}
```

Comment: `action.payload.forEach`?